# How to create android XML file which supports all screen

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Actually am new to android development, I have created a small calculator app, in which I have developed xml for 5 inch device, which worked in my 5 inch phone . But when I switch this app to bigger size device, items get misaligned. My question is how to create XML file that's common for all device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LinearLayout` with `android:weightSum` and `android:layoutWeight` property to make layouts with having same aspect ratio.

> LinearLayout also supports assigning a weight to individual children with the android:layout_weight attribute. This attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view in terms of how much space it should occupy on the screen. A larger weight value allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view. Child views can specify a weight value, and then any remaining space in the view group is assigned to children in the proportion of their declared weight. Default weight is zero.

Read [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear)

Answer (score 0):

You may use any layout for the parent layout: linear, relative, frame, constraint but make the width and length of the parent match_parent/match_constrainst